# Reading a set of numbers until a blank line

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read lines in this format (int float int/int) until a blank line i.e. two `\n` are fed to the command line.

I have a function which reads one line and adds the numbers to list if there are any or returns null if it has detected blank line:

```
listNode *readLine(listNode *prvi){
    int min, mesec, dan;
    float raz;
    elem tmp;
    fflush(stdin);
    if(scanf("%d %f %d/%d",&min, &raz, &dan, &mesec)){ 
        tmp.minuti = min;
        tmp.razdaljina = raz;
        tmp.dan = dan;
        tmp.mesec = mesec;
        enqueue(prvi,tmp);
        return prvi;
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
if(scanf("%d %f %d/%d%*c%[^0-9]",&min, &raz, &dan, &mesec,s)!=4)
```

but it ignores new lines and although I specified not to read numbers, the s somehow picks up the first number.

I suppose it can be done easily by reading the whole line as a string and then parsing it, but I want to do it this way, by only modifying the scanf arguments.

I hope someone will come up with a handy solution.

Comment: To read _lines_ of data, consider `fgets()` and not `scanf()` even if "but I want to do it this way".  `scanf()` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Since `scanf()` doesn't care about lines but you do, the `scanf()` family of functions is the wrong tool to be using to read the lines.  In particular, `scanf()` et al will not stop because of a blank line — it will simply skip over it. It will be happy if part of the set of 4 values is on one line and the rest on two more lines; it will be happy if there are 6 sets of 4 numbers on a single line. You must read the lines as lines — use standard C `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to do so.  Then use `sscanf()` to process the data in the line.

Comment: Also, you must check that you get four values; `scanf()` will also return the non-zero value `EOF` when it reaches end of file, or if there is an I/O error, and your loop won't stop. (That call could return `EOF` or 0 .. 4.) Use: `int rc; if ((rc = scanf("…", …)) == 4) { …process normally… } else { …process error… }`.  If you don't want to analyze the error in detail, don't capture the return count in `rc`.  Note that `%d/%d` will accept `"29/    -9"` but won't accept `"29 / 13"`.  Further, there's no way to stop the `scanf()` family from skipping leading white space before any number.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My idea is to have a buffer string: If the string contains 2x \n then return null, otherwise continue the process. The problem with scanf is it starts reading string from first non white character thus it cannot detect the string \n\n\0. I wanted to see if there is a neat trick around it. I have solved it by reading the whole line and then processing it afterwards. Thank you for your helpful comments

Comment: The initial `%d` skips arbitrary white space, including newlines, tabs, blanks. You CANNOT control what `scanf()` does with newlines etc.  it doesn’t care about them; it just reads them. Trying to do otherwise Is fighting against the function. You’d have to read the data as character strings using scan sets and then convert the strings. You’re infinitely better off reading lines and then parsing them. The error reporting will be easier too.